# How to determine bang-for-buck apart from just $/TB

Tags: data-visualization, ranking

Firstly, I'm no expert on statistics or any of the fancy jargon so please pardon my ignorance and use of layman terms! Also, forgive me if this is not the right forum to post my question.

So I've been asked to choose between three different capacity storage array units. All other things equal, the only difference between the three are their capacity and price. Obviously one can easily work out which array yields the lowest price per TB - it's the fourth column and is typically that with the most capacity (due to falling storage prices). What I'm interested in is whether there are other ways to determine what is the best bang-for-buck or sweet-spot, so to speak.

Here is my data set:

```
+-------+----------+-------+------+
| Model | Capacity | Cost  | $/TB |
|       | (TB)     | ($)   |      |
+-------+----------+-------+------+
| A     | 16       | 20400 | 1275 |
+-------+----------+-------+------+
| B     | 32       | 22150 |  692 |
+-------+----------+-------+------+
| C     | 40       | 26500 |  662 |
+-------+----------+-------+------+
```

For example, whilst C is the cheapest in terms of \$/TB it also commands a hefty increase of \$4350 compared to a reduction in \$/TB of just \$30. It also has only 25% more capacity than B.

Meanwhile, B is significantly cheaper \$/TB compared to A, has double the capacity of A and yet is only \$1750 dearer.

So upon initial inspection it appears Model B offers the best bang-for-buck relative to A and C. However, is there an objective way to show this by graphing the data and showing some kind of intersection (or something) which represents the sweet spot?

Thank you so much for your time!

Comment: You can plot a pareto frontier in your multi-objective optimization problem (allowing you to eliminate dominated options, if there are any, but we can't tell you where your preferred point on the frontier should be; that depends on your preferences). This isn't really a stats problem; it's is more a topic in [economics](https://economics.stackexchange.com/search?q=multi-objective+optimization).

Comment: This isn't a matter of statistics or jargon, but of common sense. Company $X$ needs at least 35 TB of storage, so the best solution for it is to buy one C unit.  Company $Y$ needs only 1 TB storage now but in two years that will grow to 20 TB.  Maybe a purchase of B is the best, depending on their internal ROI.  Company $Z$ needs only 1 TB of storage, so the best solution for it is to buy one A unit.  These possibilities show that *no objective solution exists.*  There isn't even a subset of these options one could identify that restricts the possibilities.

Comment: Are A, B, and C equivalent in reliability, security, and speed?

Comment: @BruceET assume all the same as mentioned in question.

Comment: It would be easy to say that if you have \$26,500 available, then C may be best. But in real life decisions you can never really say "all other things are equal." As @whuber comments the buyer's plans for the future may make the difference. No use buying C if you'll never need more than 16 TB. Or if you think costs will soon decrease by an order of magnitude. Certainly,  today's \$/TB is _one_ thing to consider.

Comment: Fair call. I guess what you guys are all saying is that you need additional parameters that set a restriction, for example "I can only spend $xxx to obtain a capacity of yTB. What is the most cost effective way of achieving this?"

Comment: That's part of it, to be sure.  The other part is that it may be wise to question whether, or to what extent, dollars per terabyte is an effective basis for comparison.  What is needed is a reasonably accurate "loss function" that measures the trade-offs made among the available options.  Although there is a statistical theory (and rich economic theory) of what properties loss functions must have, it is rare that statistical theory alone can determine what the actual loss function ought to be: that information needs to be supplied with the question.